# Error : "Failed to allocate a 246903564 byte allocation with 11538218 free bytes and 79MB until OOM"

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

When running `Genymotion` via `Android Studio` the next error occurs:

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Genymotion wants to allocate 246 MB of RAM, but you only have 11 MB free.

Comment: I have in my pc 8gb of ram

Comment: if is a problem of genymotion, how can i resolve it?